# Two objects don't cast a shadow while other one does

Tags: three.js, shadow

I have exactly the same three cube objects except their x position.
I want them to cast a shadow, but somehow two of them don't cast a shadow while the other one does.

Here is the pic of what's happening.
https://ibb.co/z6Vwxmf

I'm sure that castShadow is set to true on all the objects.
And I don't think I missed any shadow setting property either (because the middle object casts a shadow properly.)

These objects are created under //left cube //right cube comments in the below code.

```
< script >

    window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

function init(event) {
    createScene();
    createLights();
    createTile01();
    createTile02();
    createTile03();
    createBase();

    loop();
}

var scene, camera, Width, Height, renderer, container;

function createScene() {

    Width = window.innerWidth;
    Height = window.innerHeight;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y = 10;
    camera.position.z = 50;
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x000000));
    renderer.setSize(Width, Height);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

    container = document.getElementById('scene');
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize, false);

}

function handleWindowResize() {
    Height = window.InnerHeight;
    Width = window.InnerWidth;
    renderer.setSize(Width, Height);
    camera.aspect = Width / Height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

var ambiLight, spotLight;

function createLights() {
    ambiLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
    scene.add(ambiLight);

    spotLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    spotLight.position.set(0, 30, -0);
    spotLight.intensity = 1;
    spotLight.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(spotLight);
}

Tile01 = function() {
    var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 10, 2);
    var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x53b0df
    });
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
    this.mesh.receiveShadow = true;
    this.mesh.castShadow = true;
}

var tile01;

function createTile01() {
    tile01 = new Tile01();
    tile01.mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    scene.add(tile01.mesh);
}

//right cube
Tile02 = function() {
    var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 10, 2);
    var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x25b0cf
    });
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
    this.mesh.receiveShadow = true;
    this.mesh.castShadow = true;
}

var tile02;

function createTile02() {
    tile02 = new Tile02();
    tile02.mesh.position.set(20, 0, 0);
    scene.add(tile02.mesh);
}

//left cube
Tile03 = function() {
    var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 10, 2);
    var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x00b0df
    });
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
    this.mesh.receiveShadow = true;
    this.mesh.castShadow = true;
}

var tile03;

function createTile03() {
    tile03 = new Tile03();
    tile03.mesh.position.set(-20, 0, 0);
    scene.add(tile03.mesh);
}

Base = function() {
    var geom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(100, 30, 5, 60);
    var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xcf34ec
    });

    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
    this.mesh.castShadow = true;
    this.mesh.receiveShadow = true;
}

var base;

function createBase() {
    base = new Base();
    base.mesh.position.set(0, -10, -20);
    scene.add(base.mesh);
}

function loop() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

< /script>
```

Could you help me figure out what's wrong with the setting?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue myself.

Referring to some solutions I found at other Q/As about a shadow issue, I added a shadow.camera.left/right/top/bottom properties to the light and it worked.

The below is the code I corrected.
Now I can see the shadows of all the three objects.

```
    var ambiLight, spotLight;
    function createLights() {
        ambiLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
        scene.add(ambiLight);

        spotLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        spotLight.position.set(0, 30, -0);
        spotLight.intensity = 1;
        spotLight.castShadow = true;

        spotLight.shadow.camera.left = -400;
        spotLight.shadow.camera.right = 400;
        spotLight.shadow.camera.top = 400;
        spotLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -400;
        spotLight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
        spotLight.shadow.camera.far = 1000;

        spotLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
        spotLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;

        scene.add(spotLight);
    }
```